# Why is my setInterval function not working? - Beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, optimization, setinterval

I am a bit of a beginner when it comes to Javascript, and using examples found on this website, I have pieced together a simple bit of code that I am able to understand, but have been unable to get working. I would be very grateful if someone could point out where I have gone wrong, and/or explain why it needs a complete overhaul if necessary.

My aim is to have 3 images in a "carousel" which alter after 4 seconds with a fade in/fade out. I was able to achieve this previously, but without the ability to make it loop.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setInterval(function () {
        num = (num + 1) % 3;
    }, 4000);

    if(num > 3) {
        num = 1;
    }

    if(num = 1) {
        $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeIn();
        $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeOut();
        $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeOut();
    }
    if(num = 2) {
        $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeOut();
        $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeIn();
        $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeOut();
    }
    if(num = 3) {
        $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeOut();
        $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeOut();
        $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: it is working - it's just not doing anything other than cycling num through 0 to 2 - or maybe not, as num isn't declared anywhere so, it's just doing nothing every 4 seconds, maybe emitting a console error .... look in the console for that

Comment: Adding HTML will help to get optimized solution

Comment: The only thing you're doing every 4 seconds is `num = ...`; the rest of the code only runs *once*.

Comment: declare `var num = 0` then drop the `if (num > 3` it never will be anything but 0, 1 or 2 (lookup the % operator) change the `if (num = ?` to `if (num == ?` because you need to know the difference between assignment, =, and equality == ... then allow for the fact that num % 3 will be 0, 1 or 2 ... so change your `if` s accordingly ... then put the if statements inside the `setinterval` anonymous function, so they are actually exectued

Comment: If all the slides are direct and only children of `.carousel` element, `var num = 0,
    numOfSlides = $('.carousel').children().length;
setInterval(function() {
    $('.carousel').eq(num++ % numOfSlides).fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
}, 4000);`

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` fires once. It does what is in your closure, then exits and never comes back. And your `setInterval()` is just looping the `num` value, the rest of the code is not executing anymore.

Check the code below. I'm not questioning the idea for now, just changed it the way it would work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num = 0;
    var action = function() {
        if(num == 0) { // note the comparison: it's ==, not =
            $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeIn();
            $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeOut();
            $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeOut();
        } else if(num == 1) {
            $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeOut();
            $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeIn();
            $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeOut();
        } else if(num == 2) {
            $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeOut();
            $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeOut();
            $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeIn();
        }       
        num = (num + 1) % 3;
    };

    setInterval(action, 4000);
    action();
});
```

Comment: There are better answers here.

Answer (score 3):

Don't repeat yourself:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num = 0;
    var action = function() {
        $(".carousel #slide-" + (num % 3) + 1).fadeIn();
        $(".carousel #slide-" + ((num + 1) % 3) + 1).fadeOut();
        $(".carousel #slide-" + ((num + 2) % 3) + 1).fadeOut();
        num = (num + 1);
    };
    setInterval(action, 4000);
    action();
});
```

Or, better yet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slides = [
        $(".carousel #slide-1"),
        $(".carousel #slide-2"),
        $(".carousel #slide-3")
    ];
    var action = function() {
        slides[0].fadeIn();
        slides[1].fadeOut();
        slides[2].fadeOut();
        slides.push(slides.shift());
    };
    setInterval(action, 4000);
    action();
});
```

And my final thought:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slides = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.carousel [id^="slide-"]'));
    var action = function() {
        slides[0].fadeOut();
        slides[1].fadeIn();
        slides.push(slides.shift());
    };
    setInterval(action, 4000);
    slides.reduce(function(ignore, slide) { // fade out all slides after the first
        slide.fadeOut();
    });
    slide[0].fadeIn(); // fade in the first
});
```

Comment: I thought about it at first, but I decided it would a little bit over the top for now. :) Nice alternative anyway.

Comment: I like the middle solution myself, kudos for providing some nice options.

Comment: @paxdiablo - the beauty of the last one is that you don't need to change the code to change the number of slides

Answer (score 2):

Don't hard code it. Let it be dynamic. This code will adapt to any number of child images under `.carousel`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var imgs = $('.carousel > img'),
      cur = 0;
  
  imgs.slice(1).hide();
  
  setInterval(function() {
    var hidden = cur;
    
    if (++cur >= imgs.length)
      cur = 0;
    
    if (hidden !== cur) {
      imgs.eq(hidden).fadeOut();
      imgs.eq(cur).fadeIn();
    }
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel > img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100&text=1">
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100&text=2">
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100&text=3">
</div>
```

EDIT: updated to only touch the element fading in and the element fading out.

EDIT: fixed fade bug that happened if there is one image.

Comment: Nice! But really, this is a huge overkill of an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your repeating function is doing nothing more than cycling through the numeric values at the moment, since the code to adjust the DOM elements is *outside* of it.

You should move *all* of the code inside the repeating function, with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        num = (num + 1) % 3;
        if(num == 0) {
            $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeIn();
            $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeOut();
            $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeOut();
            return;
        }
        if(num == 1) {
            $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeOut();
            $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeIn();
            $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeOut();
            return;
        }
        if(num == 2) {
            $(".carousel #slide-1").fadeOut();
            $(".carousel #slide-2").fadeOut();
            $(".carousel #slide-3").fadeIn();
        }
    }, 4000);
});
```

You'll notice some *other* changes I made as well, hopefully I've caught all of them but there may be others:

- initialise the `num` variable.
- equality checking isn't done with `=` but with `==` or `===`.
- the statement `num = (num + 1) % 3;` already cycles through `{0, 1, 2}` so there's no need for other checks.
- the `if` statements have been modified to use `{0,1,2}` rather than `{1,2,3}`.
- `return` has been added to the first two `if` blocks since there's no need to continue once you've chosen one of them.

Comment: and fix the fundamental errors in the code too - bravo :p

Comment: Aw, I was late by a couple of minutes, but did pretty much the same. :)

Comment: Consider using `else if` or `return` in the `if` condition after fades.

Comment: I think `else if` is better than `return`.

Comment: @paxdiablo there's still one thing where my solution is more correct: the initial code, as ruined as it may be, executes this "carousel" thing and then waits for 4 seconds, while your code starts with waiting.

Comment: And my quess is that it was actually intended to run the first block on the first pass, so I moved the `num = (num + 1) % 3;` to the end. Anyway, the answer is very nice and elaborate.

Comment: @Nox, that would be covered by my "there may be others" comment. My original intent wasn't so much to fix every single issue but just to explain why it wasn't working. The other issues started as syntax fixes but got out of hand. In any case, the initial HTML setup may have image 1 already visible with 2 and 3 invisible - yes, I'm clutching at straws there :-).